# How to store web session in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

When a user click on some page in web application, it moves to the next window and the previous window gets expired immediately. Now after performing some actions on new window, i want to move back to the previous window but as said that the session gets expired.

Can this be done with selenium web driver.

Comment: How would you do this as a manual test?

Comment: if session is ended how you can back to it? even if you store all cookies information ?

Comment: that is what i am asking.. if the session gets closed. Is there any possibility in selenium webdriver to store that session and use it later. Can RemoteWebDriver do this task, bcoz it has driver.getSessionId() method availlable? Please revert.